# How can I automatically move a robot's body to the correct height based on its leg(s) rotation?

Tags: constraints, drivers

When I rotate the leg the body or the luggage bag should come down slowly. Which constraint or any other way will achieve this?

[image: gif] [video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjXxv.jpg)

[Blend File](https://pasteall.org/blend/2ff45f8aa25d4a558775d32ccd167b2d)

Comment: you could use a driver (or simply move the luggage down with some keyframes)? Please edit your question and put some pictures

Comment: i am not totally sure, but do you want something like this?  https://youtu.be/YjzCMA_TxBA.  -> be a bit patient, my internet upload speed greets every bit with handshake.... :(

Comment: i upvoted the question, because of your blend file ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can parent the leg to the body so it moves automatically when the body moves, then with the leg selected, in the *Numbers Panel* right-click on the *X rotation*, *Copy as New Driver*, select the body, right-click on the *Z location*, *Paste Driver*. The body will now drop down to Z = 0, because that's the current rotation of the leg (at least in my case). Now you may notice the body moves based on the leg's rotation, but not yet correctly:

[image]

To properly convert the angle to a vertical offset caused by it, trigonometry has to be used:

[image]

In my example the length of the leg is not exactly `1`, so I need to multiply that length (`2`) by the cosine, and the formula, in my case, becomes: `2 * cos(rotation_euler)`.

With the body selected, right-click on the *Z location* again, and choose *Edit Driver*. Change its type from *Average Value* to *Scripted Expression*, and update the formula to correctly base the body's height on the leg's rotation:

[image]

Effect:

[image]

There's some additional problems to be dealt with:

- position of the leg lags 1 frame behind, because while it's based (due to parenting) on the cube, the cube is also based on it (due to the driver); the solution is to clear the parenting and copy-paste the driver from the cube's position also to the leg's position;
- the formula assumes the leg has 0 thickness; the simplest solution is to put a sphere on the bottom of it and add an additional offset in the formula equal to the radius of the the sphere;
- the body can fall through the floor; the solution is to either use a constraint (and because the leg is not parented that means another constraint for it as well), or use `max()` in the driver to clamp the minimum value, like so: `max(1, 2 * cos(rotation_euler))`

Comment: Thanks what needed can u plz show me on the attach blend file.

Comment: @atek tell me what's confusing in my answer and I'll try to clarify.

Comment: I have a limit rotation constraint on the leg. Do i have to remove or not and from here i did not get and add an offset which was the original body's position before adding the driver. Now you may notice the body moves based on the leg's rotation, but not yet correctly:

Comment: I updated the answer, hopefully it's less confusing now.

Comment: When i parent the bag to the handle the bag is not connected to the handle. https://imgur.com/a/VtLoEnK.

Comment: @atek see if rotating the handle afterwards will fix that - see "position of the leg lags 1 frame behind" and how to fix that. I think an even better solution than what I proposed is to parent the bag to the handle, and drive the handle's position based on its rotation, not the bag's position based on handle's rotation. 

Comment: Its not working on the model